# sed is appending using $stringvar literally instead of using variable's contents

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to get sed to append a line after a string of text in a file but it's using the replacement string literally instead of the contents of the variable.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.cpp; do
  echo "Checking file $i"
  if grep -Fxq "//junkStringHere" "$i"
  then
    junk=$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
    echo $junk
    sed -i '/.*//junkStringHere.*/a \\${!junk}' "$i"
  else
    echo "Nothing to do."
  fi
done
```

I've tried all iterations of $junk I can think of/read online too.

```
$junk "$junk" \\$junk" '$junk' ${!junk} ${junk} etc...
```

However, all that gets returned in the example.cpp is

```
//example.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//junkStringHere
${!junk}" <- this is what is placed in the document.

    cout << "This is a test.";
}
```

or whatever variation of it is being used in the command. This is just an example, I want the $junk string to appear on a new line below the "//junkStringHere" in the file.

If I echo the junk variable before it parses through sed it returns the proper contents however I can't get sed to work properly. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That's not a sed issue, but a shell one. Shell doesn't expand variables in single quotes, use double quotes. Sed knows nothing about shell variables.

Comment: I'm getting the same output regardless of what variation of quotations or brackets I use.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes don't expand variables, use double quotes. You need to backslash the backslash in double quotes, though:

```
$ echo XXX junkStringHere XXX | (junk="USER"; sed "/.*junkStringHere.*/a \\
     ${!junk}")
XXX junkStringHere XXX
    choroba
```

Comment: Replacing the double quotes with \\ changes the output in the file to ${!junk}\ and replacing both changes it too ${!junk}" with a double quote on the end.

Comment: Please, provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I clearly demonstrated it should be possible.

Comment: I edited the main post to explain things better with copy/paste code.

Comment: Why do you use the `!` there?

Comment: Just trying different variations of how to use variables in sed I've found online. \\$junk" or \\${junk}" don't work either.

Comment: Just use `$junk` or `${junk}`. The `!` is used for indirection which you don't need here.

Comment: Using `$junk` or `${junk}` still doesn't write the variable's contents into the .cpp file.

Comment: @Jai you are causing your own problems by thrashing around trying to solve multiple problems simultaneously without understanding any of them nor the "solutions" your attempting. Focus on one problem (e.g. expanding a shell variable inside a sed script), solve that, THEN move onto the next problem (e.g. changing the input file).

Answer (score -2):

I ""fixed"" it by using gawk instead.

```
gawk -i inplace '/junkStringHere/{print;print "'"$junk"'";next}1' "$i"
```